# How to take screenshot before my activity launch

Tags: android, android-bitmap, android-screen, android-background

I am creating an android app in which I want to take screenshot of my device when i click on myapp icon and when myapp launch set the screenshot as background of myactivity, I searched alot but cant find any solution anyone please tell me how i can achieve this task?

Answer (score 0):

When users click on the launcher icon (the icon of your application in the menu of your device) the application is launched.

This is managed by *Android* itself and you can't override/change this behavior.

It means that it is not possible to do something on the device before your application is launched.